# How to use a node of FXML class from an other class controller?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I need to create an object of opened fxml class but 
when I create object of that class, gives me a run exception ( attached below ) I tried various shapes around this code but I get the same excption at best case scinario.

this is the fxml class controller which have the node ( tabpane ) and the method I need to access.

```
public class main{
@FXML
private TabPane tab_pane;

public void accountReportTab(){
    if(Controller.current_user.get(0).getView_account_report() == 1 ){
        account_report_tab.setText("account report");
        account_report_tab.setId("account_report");
        account_report_tab.setContent(account_report_root);
        if( ! tab_pane.getTabs().contains(account_report_tab)){
            tab_pane.getTabs().add(account_report_tab);
        }
        tab_pane.getSelectionModel().select((account_report_tab));
    }else {
        launcher.noAccessStage();
    }
}
}
```

the other controller method which I know it's a wrong accessing to the method ( or main is not the right controller)
- ps: I can access it right with Class.object but I can't set `accountReportTab()` to static

```
public class accounts{
Main main = new Main();
@FXML
void account_report_btn(ActionEvent event) {
    // open account statement tab with account id to get reports...
    main.accountReportTab();
}
}
```

I even tried creating an object like this

```
@FXML
private Main main;
```

run time exception is

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 52 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at user_interface_controller.accounts.Accounts.account_report_btn(Accounts.java:106)
    ... 62 more

in the accounts class but it as expected doesn't work, please give me a detailed answer.

Comment: Please add the exception to the question.

Comment: It works with this : Main.account_report_tab(); but I can't make this method static for various reasons.

Comment: @Boris what exception ?

Comment: The one you mentioned in the question: "gives me a run exception".

Comment: I doubt if you can get real help based on the code posted. Please post [mre]

Comment: @Boris ok I want to do this https://riptutorial.com/javafx/example/8803/passing-data-to-fxml---accessing-existing-controller but I get exception of null pointer based on InvocationTargetException when I try to use controller as global.

Comment: So, please copy and paste the exception to the question.

Comment: @Boris added , thank you so much for your concern.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: It's ok I wanted a Singleton insurance but it needs a trick with FXML UI. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a NullPointerException at `Accounts.java` line 106. Can you analyse it? Maybe update the question with the relevant code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't comment to ask for clarification, but do you want to access a component from a different stage, or from the current? It is unclear but there are work arounds..

To access an object of the current stage you can use a component from your current window like this:
Stage stage = (Stage) YOURCOMPONENT.getScene().getWindow();

If you are trying to access another stage you might try a Singleton approach:

https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-singleton

Comment: I actually asked about Singleton on quora but I got nothing , but with your answer  at singleton again I've tried it again and shake it up a little and it works thank you so much.

Comment: No problem at all, welcome to stack.

If the answer suits you, please accept it by clicking the check sign beside my answer

Comment: sorry about who ever down voted you're answer I answered more detailed one. thanks a lot man

Answer (score -1):

simply you need a singleton class, to do that

```
public class Controller{
   private static Controller instance;
   private Controller(){}
   public static Controller getInstance(){
       if(instance == null ){
           instance = new Controller();
       }
       return instance;
   }
 .....
}
```

but still a trick if you're dealing with a fxml class which is setting instance as controller factory which you can do while loading fxml as follow.

```
Parent root= null;
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(string path to fxml class));
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory( c ->{
        return Controller.getInstance();
    });
    try{
        root =  fxmlLoader.load();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```